# How to substring Regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input which can have up to 50 ASCII characters with a hidden pattern that I need to find. The pattern is the letter A (case insensitive) followed by 8 digits. Only the first pattern (if exists) needs to be found. So an example input can be lkjs#$9234A12345678*)(&kj

How do I do this in JavaScript?

```
var input = 'lkjs#$9234A12345678*)(&kj';
var regex = '[Aa][0-9]{8}';
var index = input.search(regex);
if (index >= 0) {
    //found pattern - but how to extract it???
}
```

Comment: you know how long the pattern is so you can use string.substring()

Comment: Do you search in cardData ? in input ?

Comment: sorry, incorrect variable name in question  - edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

```
var match = input.match(/a\d{8}/i); // yes, that's an equivalent regular expression
if (match) { // if a match is found
     var str = match[0];
     // here you go, str is your "substring"
}
```